# JFrame resize only with the maximize and minimize button?

Tags: button, jframe, resize, mouse, maximize

is it possible to resize a JFrame only with the maximize and minimize buttons?
I mean so that the user can´t resize the window dragging it.
I know there is the ComponentAdapter, but it fires also if you drag the window.
The window listener would be an option, if you are able to block the dragging of the window without blocking the resizing through the buttons.
Please let me know when you have an idea. :P

Comment: Have you tried setting the frame to not been resizable `setResizable` - Just note, as a user, I will hate you for it

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I tried that recently, but then the maximize button will change to a lighter gray and you dont have the option to press it. It isnt my original problem. My problem is the following: In my application I have a kind of animation which slows down when you drag the window frequently. This should be only a workaround. :P

Comment: Maybe Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.setDynamicLayout(false)  does it :)

Comment: No- that controls when a layout pass is triggered